# Solution of $u' = Au$ with $A$ skew-symmetric

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

As an application of Noether's theorem there's this application which involves a Lagrangian of the form $$L(q,\dot{q}) = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{q}^2-V(\lvert q \rvert)$$

Which is invariant for the action of rotation of arbitrary angle $\alpha$ around a direction $a$ (so $\lvert a \rvert = 1$) which we will call $\varphi(q,\alpha) = R_{\alpha}(a)q$.

What I don't understand is that in order to compute the generator of the action $\xi(q) = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial \alpha}(q,0)$ we use the following fact :

Given $a = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3\end{pmatrix}$, the solution of $u' = Au$ with initial value $u_0$ is given by both $u = e^{At}u_0$ and $u = R_{\alpha}(a)$, where $A$ is the skew-symmetric matrix with $a_{1,2} = -a_3, a_{1,3} = a_2, a_{2,3} = -a_1$.

I don't understand why $u = R_{\alpha}(a)$ is a solution since I'm unable to compute its derivative respect to $t$ due to its general form. Is this a consequence of ODE theory?

Comment: What do know about Lie groups and Lie algebras? It is a general approach to such questions.

Comment: @TimurBakiev just the definition of Lie group, not much more

Comment: ok, let’s go another way…

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. Prove $e^{At}$ is an orthogonal matrix and its determinant $> 0$. This follows from the skew-symmetricity of $A$ and properties of the exponent function.
2. Prove that $A a = 0$. Derive from this fact the equality $e^{At}a = a$.
   So we’re actually dealing with some rotation around $a$.
3. Show that $e^{At}$ is not periodic.
   It’s okay, since $S^1$ is compact, and the real line is not, the solution can’t give you all rotations around the axis, but all except one. The parameter $t$, as you can see, does not correspond to the angle in an obvious way. In fact, $e^{At}$ is a solution only locally, and $R_\alpha(a)$ is a global solution glued from several (in fact, two) local solutions. A parametrization doesn’t matter as long as we consider only integral curves.